# Object has no color dispite whatever I do

Tags: image, color

The figurine has no color dispite whatever I do. The material was assigned to the object but it still doesn't pick up any color. The only colors are the white clouds and the green grass that the figurine is standing on. And when I click on materials, the tiny image turns white! [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You haven't activated nodes and the texture isn't assigned to the material, but as brush.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your texture to the material. Create the *Shading* workspace by clicking the plus button next to the other workspaces or change the *3D View* to the *Shader Editor*

[image]

Activate *Use Nodes* then select the material you want to edit and then set up a basic shader with a texture like in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question!!